# Hide sheets but keep macros that refence them working

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 5 sheets. The 5th is made of a bunch of macros that use data from 1 to 4.

I want to hide 1 to 4 but then the macros in the fifth don't work because they can't 'see' 1 to 4.

Have I actually hit an limitation of excel ?

Comment: No, it's not a limitation of Excel. If you want more help, please show your code.

Comment: If your code includes commands like `Select` or `Activate` they won't work on hidden sheets. Take them out. You can access any part of any sheet, hidden or not, without selecting anything.

Comment: I do use `Sheets("sheet-name").select`. What would be the alternative?

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859482/excel-2013-vba-alternative-to-using-activate-and-select` full path to datapoint explain in here seem to be the way

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) very popular question should help. Without seeing your code, your'e not likely to get anything more specific really